# I need practical tools or workshop tips to create product vision for an existing product

Tags: scrum, vision, product

I am familiar with the product vision but never used it so far since I joined once it was already done

I have been appointed to a project where 2 existing products are overlapping and we need to set up an agile project to understand if is better to merge the products or seek and develop whatever other solution is better. I will be scrum master in this project and I have been asked to set up a sprint zero starting with a workshop for the stakeholders to create a product vision and product backlog.

Does anyone have any practical suggestion how to structure a workshop to do that work?
stakeholders are mainly managers, is it correct that they come up with the content of the product vision in the workshop?

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of variables in your situation that I don't know the answer to and so I'll try to keep my suggestions as high-level as I can. Either way, please use them as only a starting point.

**5 Levels of Planning**

First I'd look at the 5 levels of planning. There's a lot of info to look up on this, but the short version is that they are:

Vision Planning
Roadmap Planning
Release Planning
Sprint Planning
Daily Planning (Scrum)

Depending on the length of your workshop, you're looking at Vision and maybe some roadmap.

**Vision Planning**

Product vision is just part of this. If you haven't used other product vision approaches before, I'd look at the elevator pitch format and the product box exercise (design the imaginary box your product will come in). These are great ways to get ideas flowing. The second option could easily be a workshop in itself since it'll get into things like key features and constraints.

Vision planning may also include things like stakeholder maps, constraints, and personas.

**Roadmap Planning**

There are a lot of ways to approach this. Two good options are:

*Lean Project Canvas to prioritize major features*:

http://www.agile42.com/en/blog/2013/04/11/lean-project-canvas/

Full disclosure, I know the author, so I'm not unbiased here, but it is a technique I like and use myself.

Short version of this is you brainstorm major features and use these canvases to give them a good apples-to-apples comparison for prioritization.

*Story Mapping*

There's a lot on the internet about story mapping and it would be ungainly for me to try to describe it here. Going through a full-blown story map here is probably taking it too far. The narrative aspect of a story map is what I'd focus on. How do they see a customer going through the major features? This can also act as a foundation when you bring the other teams in to start digging in.

I hope this helps. Start with that 5 levels of planning idea and you'll find tons of other approaches out there too. For the most part, they're all good. Just find the one that fits for you.